# First element allready clicked

Tags: html, menu, click, accordion

Based on this
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

I need the first "section 1" to be allready clicked in default

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**tl:dr**: Remove the style `display: none`.

You can create another class in the CSS with:

```
.panelshow {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And then set the class of the  to panel1 like so:

```
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panelshow">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Result:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.panelshow{
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panelshow">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @MariusTrandafir Works now.

Comment: @MariusTrandafir If this helps, it would be helpful if you accepted my answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can add a class called open like this:

```css
.open {
 display: block;
}
```

then have the panel you want opened has that class like: `<div class="panel open"></>`

also give the first accordion class the active class like : `<button class="accordion active">Section 1</button>`

and just toggle between them each time.